# struts2 dojo button handler moving into a closure

Tags: javascript, dojo, closures

Using Struts2 with tiles and dojo something released in last 2 years.  trying to move gobal code 
for button onclick  and form validation into a closure.

------myjsp.jsp page-----

`function doDialog(){

var myVar = new MyNewDialog(42);

myVar.showDialog();

}

......

< button ... to show dialog.. onclick="doDialog()" ..../>

< tiles:insertTemplate  template="myDialog.jsp"


.....`

--------myDialog.jsp----

`< script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"/>`

....

< div dojoType="dijit.form.Button" iconClass="toolbarIcon toolbarIconSave"
                     id="mySaveButtonId" showLabel="true" onclick="mySaveButtonPressed();">
     
                < /div>

--------my.js file----

`// This function works because it is global, I want to move it into the closure.

    function mySaveButtonPressed(){

       .....

       validateDialog();

       ...

    }

  
   function validateDialog(){

      .. yes it calls the the struts2 validators... but also does some other things.

   }`

```
function MyNewDialog(param){

     this.contstrucDialog = function(){
      ...
     }

     //desired location saving code
     //this.mySaveButtonPressed = function(){
     //.....<
     //validateDialog();
     //...
     //}
     //function validateDialog(){
     //  .....
     // }

    ..... everything but the method for validating and saving the dialog data....
}
```

---

**I moved the save and validate methods into the closure, and tried add a connection to my target method.  the mySaveButtonPressed is never executed.  I thought the whole point of connect was to connect a widget event to some method call.**
  myjsp.jsp

var myVar = new MyNewPopupStuff(42);
var mySaveButton = dojo.byId("mySaveBut
\tonId");
dojo.connect(mySaveButton,"onclick", myVar.mySaveButtonPressed());
myVar.contstrucDialog();

Since I really don't want to putting a lot of "myVar" stuff anywhere, I tried "this" instead of myVar.  no luck.

QUESTION: How should I move this code into a closure????

--------------------------Had a thought but cannot test it at moment------

Perhaps the dojo.connect should go into the closure where I construct the dialog contents.

QUESTION:  What is the industry best practice for handling this common delema?

Answer (score 0):

in my java script that built the dialog I put the javascript that built my dialog.

works

function MyNewDialog(param){

```
 this.contstrucDialog = function(){
  ...
  dojo.connect(saveButton,"onclick",this,mySaveButtonPressed,true );
   ......
 }
```

but does not like

dojo.connect(saveButton,"onclick",this,mySaveButtonPressed(),true )

So minor question that someone may be able to answer for me.  When do I put parens when do I not?
I am calling a function mySaveButtonPressed(),  Why would'nt I use "mySaveButtonPressed()"?